# Google forms and google sheet integration - populate data's of google sheet into google form dropdown using appscript

Tags: forms, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

i've a requirement, where in my google form i've multiple dropdowns and here (in dropdown) i've to show the data's from the table (which is in google sheet i.e like microsoft excel).

so, i've to fetch these data from sheet(google sheet) and show these data in the google form drop down ( basically i want to do it using appscript)

so can someone help or suggest any good way to do this??

Answer (score 1):

```
function populateFormDropdown(){
  const form = FormApp.openById("YOUR_FORM_ID")
  const listItem = form.addListItem()
  
  // fetch your labels from data source
  const labels = ["item1", "item2", "item3"]

  const choices = labels.map(label=>listItem.createChoice(label))
  listItem.setChoices(choices)
}
```